# Localizar aplicativo pela busca da play store

Tags: android, google-play

Publiquei pela primeira vez um app do Google Play Store, mais para teste mesmo,
o google que entra direto na página do aplicativo. O link funciona, mas queria encontrar ele pela busca e não consigo.

Alguém sabe me dizer se tem alguma coisa que tenho que fazer para o aplicativo aparecer nas buscas? Estou meio perdido no console do Google Play Developer ainda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A pesquisa do Google Play é uma ferramenta-chave para usuários
> encontrarem apps importantes e populares para dispositivos Android.
> Garantir que seu app e os detalhes dele sejam detalhados e otimizados
> é um fator importante para ser descoberto por usuários no Google Play.

De acordo com o Google, desenvolvedora da plataforma Android, o texto dos detalhes do seu *app* são cruciais para a descoberta dele, começando pelo título:

#### Título

- Deve ser único e acessível. Evite termos comuns e reforce a temática do seu app.
- Tenha como foco seu título, pois títulos mais longos provavelmente ficarão truncados dependendo do dispositivo que seus usuários utilizarem.
- Evite erros sutis de ortografia de termos gerais, já que os usuários podem corrigir erros de ortografia de termos de pesquisa.

Veja mais detalhes na documentação de suporte do próprio Google de [como fazer com que seu *app* seja mais fácil de encontrar na pesquisa do Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=pt-BR). E além disso também, você pode dar uma lida também sobre [como funciona a pesquisa](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186394?hl=pt-BR).